# Watson Assistant in Swift 4 Producing Error

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to connect an iOS project, coded in Swift, to an instance of a Watson Assistant that I've already created. The issue is, I can't get past a "Contextual Closure type" error in compiling.

I'm relatively new to Swift and I have yet to come across a solution.

The error arises in the block of code provided by IBM themselves (here's the link: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/swift/machine_learning/conversation.html#before-you-begin). The one thing I could find was that this is likely a result of the update to Swift 4. Below is the function that's producing the error; more specifically, it's the "response in" statement, after the third comment.

```
func assistantExample() {
    // Assistant credentials
    let username = "shawn.soneja85@gmail.com"
    let password = "Shawn8135!"
    let workspace = "199b1f99-b28c-4b3f-b610-5933328141d5"

    // instantiate service
    let assistant = Assistant(username: username, password: password, version: "2018-03-01")

    // start a conversation
    assistant.message(workspaceID: workspace) { response in
        print("Conversation ID: \(response.context.conversationID!)")
        print("Response: \(response.output.text.joined())")

        // continue assistant
        print("Request: turn the radio on")
        let input = InputData(text: "turn the radio on")
        let request = MessageRequest(input: input, context: response.context)
        assistant.message(workspaceID: workspace, request: request) { response in
            print("Response: \(response.output.text.joined())")
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the error itself:

Contextual closure type '(RestResponse?, WatsonError?) -> Void' (aka '(Optional>, Optional) -> ()') expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body

Update: 
I've tried replacing "response" with "(response, error)", but that leads to the following error messages: 
Value of type 'RestResponse?' has no member 'context'
Value of type 'RestResponse?' has no member 'output'
And with "(error, response)", it leads to the following error:
Value of type 'WatsonError?' (aka 'Optional') has no member 'output'
Value of type 'WatsonError?' (aka 'Optional') has no member 'context'

Here is documentation on .message function:
[first screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEdxv.png)
[second screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YePs.png)

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: it seems that your `message` method's completion block requires two parameters in the closure. You can try changing `{ response in` to `{ (response, error) in`. FYI: I know nothing of Watson, just trying to guess here with the error.

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestion! I

I've been playing around with adding a different argument, but run into a few different errors that I've written above.

Comment: can you Option+Click on the `.message` function and copy/paste its signature here, it may be that the two parameters are `(error, response)` instead of `(response, error)`

Comment: Also, tell me does the compiler complain for the two instances of the `.message` function? One of those as an extra `context` parameter (which may be optional).

Comment: Appreciate the continued help. 

I tried (error, response), and it indicates the same error, now saying that 'WatsonError?' has no member 'context' or 'output' (noted above as well). 

I've attached all the information after option-clicking the .message fxn

Comment: And it's a great point that the second .message function uses an additional paramter--I'm looking into it now.

Comment: Hey FJ, just commenting to let you an answer below solved the problem. Thanks again for the help

Comment: @ShawnTheDown glad you got it resolved!

Comment: @ShawntheDon it would be nice of you to upvote the suggestions FJ de Brienne, since you did not give the line number of the error, he was still able to help you make progress on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RestResponse` contains a result of the `.message` call in a field called `result`. So to access the `output` or `context`, use `response.result.output` and `response.result.context`.

Comment: This worked for me, although the final product looked like: 
"response!.result?.context", and "response?.result!.context" worked as well. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you gave more description like:

1. Swift version you are using to compile your target
2. Line number of the error

That being said, I think your problem is in the nested `.message` method, i've copied your code above but deleted some lines to try and make it clear (at least what I am proposing), you may have added the second parameter to the callback in the first call to `.message` but had forgotten to do so in the second (nested) call, the one where you pass in the `request`. So you might have added the second, `error` parameter in the first call but got the same exact error message for a missing parameter because you forgot to do the same thing for the nested call. I hope this helps :)

```
// start a conversation
assistant.message(workspaceID: workspace) { response, error in
    let input = InputData(text: "turn the radio on")
    let request = MessageRequest(input: input, context: response.context)
    assistant.message(workspaceID: workspace, request: request) { response, error in
        print("Response: \(response.output.text.joined())")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! Unfortunately, "response.context" on line 4 of your function still boasted the same error, indicating that response didn't have that attribute--even with "response, error" used in both .message() functions. Regardless, your help was appreciated.

Comment: @ShawntheDon thanks. Lets take a look... What line number was your original error (the one you posted about) coming from?